# Возвращать дополнительно текстовое значение

Tags: java, android

Есть метод и коротко о нём:

```
String fromDateString = DateTools.formatToLongDateFormat(datePeriod.startDate);
String toDateString = DateTools.formatToLongDateFormat(datePeriod.endDate);
```

Дальше пишу условия при котором мои значения равны.

```
if (datePeriod.startDate.isEqual(datePeriod.endDate)) {
            return fromDateString;
        }
```

И что получается, вместо двух дат я получаю одну, но не суть важно, суть в том, что задача состоит в том, что при выполнении этого условия, а именно когда starDate = endDate , помимо return fromDateString; Выводилось дополнительно текстовое значение TODAY.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Теперь можно возвращать несколько разнотипных значений из метода без создания лишних классов используя [`android.util.Pair<F, S>`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html) так

```
pubic Pair<String, String> getPair() {
    return new Pair<String, String>("firstString", "secondString");
}
```

Получать данные надо так:

```
String first = getPair().first;
String second = getPair().second;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну Вы можете просто добавить выше `return'a` следующее:

```
fromDateString = "TODAY";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String fromDateString = DateTools.formatToLongDateFormat(datePeriod.startDate);
String toDateString = DateTools.formatToLongDateFormat(datePeriod.endDate);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("TODAY - ");
sb.append(fromDateString);

if (datePeriod.startDate.isEqual(datePeriod.endDate)) {
    return sb;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (datePeriod.startDate.isEqual(datePeriod.endDate)) {

    fromDateString="TODAY - " + fromDateString;
    return fromDateString;
}
```